# Copy pointer to aiScene

Tags: c++, assimp

I do skeletal animations using Assimp. Accordingly, I always need the data loaded by it. But for some reason, this data becomes inaccessible and results in a Segmentation fault. Below is the problem code:

```
static Mesh processMesh(const aiMesh *aimesh, const aiScene *scene) {
    Mesh mesh;
    mesh.ai_scene = scene;
    std::cout << mesh.ai_scene->mRootNode->mName.data; // OK

    ...
}
```

But if you do it inside the Mesh itself, it will lead to an error. For example:

```
void boneTransform(float TimeInSeconds) {
    glm::mat4 identity = glm::mat4();
    std::cout << ai_scene->mRootNode->mName.data; // SEG FAULT
    ...
}
```

**EDIT:**
`ai_scene` is in the Mesh structure:

```
private:
const aiScene *ai_scene = nullptr;
```

The scene itself is created in the Model structure as follows:

```
void init(const std::string &path, const GLuint params) {
    // Create an instance of the Importer class
    Assimp::Importer importer;
    const aiScene *scene = importer.ReadFile(path, params);

    // If the import failed, report it
    if (!scene) {
        std::cout << importer.GetErrorString() << "\n";
        return;
    }

    processNode(scene->mRootNode, scene);
}
```

`processNode` code:

```
void processNode(const aiNode *node, const aiScene *scene) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < node->mNumMeshes; i++) {
        aiMesh *mesh = scene->mMeshes[node->mMeshes[i]];
        meshes.push_back(Mesh::processMesh(mesh, scene));       
    }

    for(size_t i = 0; i < node->mNumChildren; i++) {
        processNode(node->mChildren[i], scene);
    }
}
```

What is this problem? And how to solve it?

Comment: Where does `ai_scene` in the second example come from? Please post a [mcve]. Also include how and where `aiMesh` is created

Comment: However using smart pointers is very likely going to fix this - you are almost certainly storing a pointer to an object that gets deleted

Comment: It seems the problem has been solved by expanding the scope of `Assimp::Importer importer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem has been solved by expanding the scope of `Assimp::Importer importer`:

```
// Create an instance of the Importer class
Assimp::Importer importer;
void init(const std::string &path, const GLuint params) {
    const aiScene *scene = importer.ReadFile(path, params);
    ...
}
```